# Strange tomcat 8 and java 8 behavior during logout

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, logout

I had a web application working with Tomcat 6.0.41 and Java 1.7.0_60.
I migrated this web app to a new server with the same version of the java package but with tomcat 8.0.15 and java 1.8.0_25.

The problem is that when several users logout in my web app, the logout is not "working".
When they click on logout:
1. valueUnbound is called
2. valueBound is called

When I click on logout button, the logout is working:
1. valueUnbound is called
and I'm correctly logged out of the app but others users are.

Do you know if there is something that is needed in tomcat or java configuration in order to not have this issue?

Comment: So is this the same version of Java or not? You say it is, but then give your "new server" Java version is 1.8.

Comment: Write an `HttpSessionBindingListener` and write-out a stack-trace whenever something interesting happens. You'll see why things are being bound/unbound.